# Stripe two types of payments on my website

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, stripe-payments

i need help with implementing Stripe.

I have added subscriptions with 4 different plans and for now it all runs smoothly. I have a form and based on what plan user selects it charges them accordingly. Form is linked to charge.php and charge.js files.

Problem is my customer is now requiring that, besides those subscriptions that already exist on the website, we add donations and recurring donations.

My question is how should i proceed about this?

Should i make different files, for example charge2.php and charge2.js and proceed from there, or is it better that i include some if statements in my original charge.php to see if user wants to donate or subscribe.

```
<?php

require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('xxx');
// Get the token from the JS script
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
// user info
$plan = $_POST['plan'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$lastName = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
// Create a Customer
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    "email" => $email,
    "source" => $token,
    'metadata' => array("name" => $name, "last_name" => $lastName, "city" => $city)
));

$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
    "customer" => $customer->id,
    "plan" => $plan,
    'metadata' => array("name" => $name, "last_name" => $lastName, "city" => $city)
));
print_r($subscription);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you are using laravel (I see you tagged laravel-5, but your example code does not appear to be using laravel), I would create a StripeController that handles all processing for Stripe payments. You can then have separate functions to handle the different payments/subscriptions.

Comment: I am indeed using laravel 5, thank you very much for your comment now i have a clue in which direction i should move on.

Answer (score 0):

I think in both  recurring donation and subscription you have to charge the customer

There are two ways to achieve recurring donation

1. Create a fixed plan for donations
2. Create a plan of the amount entered by the customer.

To handle simple payments you can directly charge your client for the donation amount.